# Recieve BLE info and pass along information through UART on TI CC2640R2F

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been looking at TI's training material for 4 days and feel like I'm getting no where. I think this should be a pretty basic task but don't even know where to start.

I need to receive a Bluetooth Low Energy packet from a Android device that will have information on 24bit Color and which LED to change. I need to pass this information through a UART port to a MSP432, as well as have a UART port that controls the CC2640R2F. I have looked through most of TI's examples and it seems there Network Processor example is closest to what I need. If someone has an example project of something similar to this or knows where to find one that explains what is going on I would be very grateful.